# Alternate solution of Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider for x64 bit version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ms-access, nunit, oledb

I am currently saving values to access database and i used Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider for this and i have configure platform mode from any cpu to x86 in my project in visual studio and it works fine with x86 platform but when i start unit testing using nunit it is not accepting x86 platform and nunit shows error

"UnitTest_Finance.Test.Class1.InsertCashPayment:
System.InvalidOperationException : The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

now i want alternative way to handle this error while performing unit testing using nunit.

here is my code for reference only

```
class RepairDLL
    {
        string dbConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/AutoRepairDB.mdb";


        //Method to Booking Value
        public virtual bool Insert_Data_Repair_History(EntityClass ec)
        {
            bool isInsert = false;

            //Connect to Database
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(dbConn);
            connection.Open();

            try
            {
                //Insert Customer Value
                string sql = "INSERT into [Repair_History] (FirstName,LastName,City,State,VehicleNo,LienseNo,RepairDate,Summary,Charge) "
                              + "VALUES ('" + ec.R_firstName + "','" + ec.R_lastName + "','" + ec.R_city + "','" + ec.R_state + "','" + ec.R_vehicleNo + "','" + ec.R_licenseNo + "','" + ec.R_date + "','" + ec.R_summary + "','" + ec.R_charge + "')";
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();

                isInsert = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception();

            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the connection
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

            return isInsert;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no 64-bit version of the Jet database engine, so 64-bit applications will have to use the 64-bit version of the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (ACE), and invoke it like this

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
```

There is also a 32-bit version of the ACE, so applications that use ACE will work in both 32-bit and 64-bit environments. Note also that Jet is deprecated for new applications.

Comment: This [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb) helped me install Acess Database Engine (ACE).